# Memory Error in Python 2.7.3

Tags: python

I'm trying to run this program on python which simulates a mindless being going around in space and to see whether it'll reach it's target.. But I'm getting a memory error every time i run it..--

```
init_posn=[0,0]
posn_final=[2,2]

obs = [[-1,1],[-1,0],[-1,1],[0,1],[1,1],[1,0],[1,-1],[0,-1]]

# algo can be improved

def obs_det(posn_x,posn_y,obs):
    for e in obs:
        if e[0]==posn_x & e[1]==posn_y:
            return 1
    return 0

posn=[]
posn.append(init_posn)

def posn_progress(posn,posn_final,obs):
    i=0
    non=0
    while (non==0 | (posn[i][0]==posn_final[0] & posn[i][1]==posn_final[1])):
        l=posn[i][0]
        m=posn[i][1]
        if obs_det(l,m+1,obs) == 0:
            posn.append([l,m+1])
        elif obs_det(l+1,m,obs) == 0:
            posn.append([l+1,m])
        elif obs_det(l,m-1,obs) == 0:
            posn.append([l,m-1])
        elif obs_det(l-1,m,obs) == 0:
            posn.append([l-1,m])
        else:
            non=1
        i=i+1
    if non==1:
        return 0
    else:
        return posn

print posn_progress(posn,posn_final,obs)
```

Comment: Why do you use bitwise operators (`|`,`&`) instead of Boolean (`||`,`&&`)? It can lead to bugs (e.g. `1&&2` is true, but `1&2` is false).

Comment: I'm reasonably sure your list is just growing until Python can't get any more memory.

Comment: Did you try debugging it? You always choose first case in if so your `posn` is equal to `([0,0],[0,1],[0,2],...` . A side note: you could use pairs `(a,b)` instead of lists `[a,b]`, they should be more memory efficient.

Comment: @ugoren: `or` and `and`, you mean.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan, Your'e right, I should stop mixing Python with C.

Comment: Using better variable/function names would make this a lot easier to follow. Use docstrings too!

Comment: Note that `obs` contains [-1,1] twice and [-1,-1] never.

Answer (score 0):

Because this looks like homework, I will answer with two hints:

1. How would you write a unit test to see if the obstacle detection routine is working as intended?
2. Read about logical and bitwise operators.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some example code; it basically does a flood-fill from the starting point until it runs into the end point.  Note that it keeps track of the places it has already been (`seen`) so it doesn't endlessly re-explore them.

```
dir = [(dx,dy) for dx in (-1,0,1) for dy in (-1,0,1) if (dx,dy)!=(0,0)]

def backtrack(b, seen):
    if seen[b]==0:
        return [b]
    else:
        seek = seen[b]-1
        x,y = b
        for dx,dy in dir:
            p = (x+dx, y+dy)
            if p in seen and seen[p]==seek:
                return backtrack(p, seen) + [b]

def find_path(a, b, dist=0, here=None, seen=None):
    if here is None: here = set([a])
    if seen is None: seen = {a:0}

    next = set()
    for x,y in here:
        for dx,dy in dir:
            p = (x+dx, y+dy)
            if p not in seen:
                seen[p] = dist+1
                next.add(p)

    if b in seen:   # found it!
        return backtrack(b, seen)
    else:
        return find_path(a, b, dist+1, next, seen)

def main():
    print find_path((0,0), (2,2))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score -1):

I think your mindless being is walking in circles.

You could teach it to avoid ever going back where it came from. Then it won't loop, but may fail to find the way, even if one exists.

Or you could make it smarter, and tell it that if it goes back, it should try a different route the next time.